# xcodebuild does not run any unit tests when launched from console

Tags: unit-tests, continuous-integration

My first question here so please bear with me. It may be off topic, if so - close the question.

I have setup Jenkins with git and Xcode plugins so that I would be able to build an iOS project on CI machine (Mac Mini). All it does is launch `xcodebuild` binary with provided parameters for target and configuration. However - I don't seem to get any unit test output. I see the compilation messages (for implementation files as well as xibs), I see the build of test bundle, but no "test passed" or "test failed" messages from test suites. Running unit tests from Xcode produces all the needed output.

What am I missing?

Comment: Welcome to SQA, Eimantas.  Do you know for a fact that the tests actually ran?

Comment: No I do not. That's the problem too. It seems that Unit tests can only be run on the device. Yet the `xcodebuild` command line utility does not detect that device is connected too! I.e. running the command equivalent in terminal - gives same result: No tests run (or no output from them).

Comment: Would it be fair to say, then, that this is not so much a Jenkins problem as an xcodebuild problem?  If so, revising the title may help attract more people with answers to xcodebuild questions.

Comment: @user246 thanks, I've revised the question title and the question itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this blog](http://longweekendmobile.com/2011/04/17/xcode4-running-application-tests-from-the-command-line-in-ios/) post it is not possible to run tests from xcodebuild but there is a work around. This problem exists for xcode 4.0 - 4.3, I'm not sure about 4.4